# Chatter Mentions with <lightning:inputRichText>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, chatter

For branding purposes, we're attempting to build our own lightning components for Chatter Feeds and we're struggling to support user input of Chatter mentions (and other Chatter objects) with the new rich text editor.

Since `<lightning:inputRichText>` removes unsupported HTML markup, we're unable to use HTML `data-` attributes on elements such as `<a href="#" data-userid="005...>@Joe Smith</>"` in the editor.

Here's a simplified component that contains the new rich text editor and a text area for entering raw HTML into the editor:

[image]

**rte.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <lightning:inputRichText aura:id="editor"/>
    <lightning:textarea aura:id="rawhtml" name="Html" label="Html" maxlength="300" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
</aura:component>
```

**rteController.js**

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var rawhtml = component.find("rawhtml").get("v.value");

        component.find("editor").set("v.value", rawhtml);
    } 
})
```

Comment: Have you managed to get this working?

Comment: @vladykx Nope...

Comment: What about now ? Did you find a solution ?